# Java alternatives to PHP indexed arrays

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over an associative array and tally up how many instances of each combination there are (for use in determining conditional probability of `A` given `B`)

For example, in PHP I can iterate over the indexed array $Data[i] given input `(A, ~B)` and get a result of 2.

```
$Data[0] = array("A", "~B");
$Data[1] = array("~A", "B");
$Data[2] = array("A", "~B");
$Data[3] = array("A", "B");
```

I tried replicating this in Java with `maps`, but maps only allow a unique key for each value... So the following wouldn't work because key `A` is being used for three entries.

```
map.put("A", "~B");
map.put("~A", "B");
map.put("A", "~B");
map.put("A", "B");
```

Is there something else I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your PHP data structure would more accurately correspond to a Java `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map<T,List<U>>` (in your case it is `Map<String,List<String>>`) or you can use a [`Multimap<String,String>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) using some library such as guava (or apache commons version of it - [`MultiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html))

Answer (score 0):

If iteration of the structure is your primary goal, a `List<ConditionResult>` would seem to be the most appropriate choice for your situation, where ConditionResult is given below.

If maintaining a count of the combinations is the sole goal, then a `Map<ConditionResult,Integer>` would also work well.

```
public class ConditionResult
{
    // Assuming strings for the data types,
    // but an enum might be more appropriate.
    private String condition;
    private String result;

    public ConditionResult(String condition, String result)
    {
        this.condition = condition;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getCondition() { return condition; }
    public String getResult() { return result; }

    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        if (this == object) return true;
        if (object == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
        ConditionResult other = (ConditionResult) object;
        if (condition == null)
        {
            if (other.condition != null) return false;
        } else if (!condition.equals(other.condition)) return false;
        if (result == null)
        {
            if (other.result != null) return false;
        } else if (!result.equals(other.result)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    // Need to implement hashCode as well, for equals consistency...

}
```

Iteration and counting could be done as:

```
/**
 * Count the instances of condition to result in the supplied results list
 */
public int countInstances(List<ConditionResult> results, String condition, String result)
{
    int count = 0;
    ConditionResult match = new ConditionResult(condition,result);
    for (ConditionResult result : results)
    {
        if (match.equals(result)) count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```